# Added product via REST API OAuth not retrieved and not able to update via REST API

Tags: magento-1.7, product, api, oauth

After adding product to Magento run `http://mymagentohost/api/rest/products/40` it will return `Resource not found` but if just open product from Magento and click on `save` (without changing anything) than (run `http://mymagentohost/api/rest/products/40`) it will return product in xml view.

some code for saving product using REST OAuth as below

```
$this->productData = array( 
            'type_id' => 'activities',
            'attribute_set_id' => 4, 
            'sku' => 'activities' . uniqid(), 
            'status' => 1, 
            'visibility' => 4, 
            'name' => 'Activities Product',
            'description' => 'Activities Description', 
            'price' => 10.00,
            'sm_product_vendor_id' => 23,
            'category_id' => 1, 
            'tax_class_id' => 0, 
........);


function saveProduct(){

try {
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($this->consumerKey, $this->consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $this->authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();
    $oauthClient->setToken($this->token, $this->secret);

    $headers =  array('Content-Type' => 'application/json');

    $oauthClient->fetch($this->resourceUrl, $this->productData, "POST", $headers);

    $this->responceInfo = $oauthClient->getLastResponseInfo();

    $this->responce = $oauthClient->getLastResponse();

} catch (OAuthException $e) {
        $this->oauthError=$e;
}
}

$this->saveProduct();
```

Response Info

```
....
    [headers_recv] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Wed, 14 Aug 2013 03:15:59 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8o
    X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.14 ZendServer
    Set-Cookie: ZDEDebuggerPresent=php,phtml,php3; path=/
    Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=rrom4add03f0ikrt6d51ej9gi5; expires=Wed, 14-Aug-2013 04:16:00 GMT; path=/magento; domain=localhost; HttpOnly
    Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
    Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
    Pragma: no-cache
    /api/rest/products/40
.....
```

when i try to run `http://mymagentohost/api/rest/products/40`

it will return **Resource not found**

```
<magento_api><messages><error><data_item><code>404</code><message>Resource not found.</message></data_item></error></messages></magento_api>
```

### Edit


while adding product via REST API following data not inserted in table (2 tables) .
if i manually add following data in table than it will be retrieved via REST API.
how to add this records using REST API

`magento_catalog_product_index_price`

[image]
`magento_catalog_product_website`
[image]

Comment: Confirmed on 1.8.1.0 this table needs rows: magento_catalog_product_website .. and after that product/category index needed to be triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to solve this by creating a custom REST API module that pretty much does this;

```
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
    $table = $resource->getTableName('catalog/product_website');
    $query = "insert into {$table} values (" .$data['product_id']. ", 1)";
    $writeConnection->query($query);
```

Replace 1 with website_id which is needed. I call this after saving the product as a separate API call. It could be inserted to the REST API in the core of course right after `$product->save();`

I did not find it necessary to add anything to `magento_catalog_product_index_price`

Pity Magento CE is not really open source so cannot do a pull request - it's more like "dumpsourceware".